# Vimeo unable to delete Old tags or put blank

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We are passing the Vimeo API args and data using csv file, we are able to put the tag when tag is empty in vimeo video but its if old tag is exiting its not replacing all old tag with new post tags.

what more can be done in that case 
 $response= $lib->request('/videos/' . $data[0].'/tags/' . $data[7], array($api_args[$c] => $data[$c]), 'PUT');

where as below code is not working
 $response= $lib->request('/videos/' . $data[0].'/tags/' . $data[7], array(), 'DELETE');

help appreciated.

Comment: Does the API return an error or other message when running that delete call?

Comment: its not returning error but its not working also like we want to put space or want to delete old tag but its not happening.